# How to minimize javascript with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, build, config, webpack, minimize

I'm trying to minimize my bundle.js file with webpack, but getting errors in my config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./entry.js",
    output: {
        devtoolLineToLine: true,
        sourceMapFilename: "./bundle.js.map",
        pathinfo: true,
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            include: /\.min\.js$/,
            minimize: true
        })
    ]
};
```

The error:

```
/Users/leongaban/Projects/TickerTags/ionic/TickerTags/www/webpack.config.js:16
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            ^
ReferenceError: webpack is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you're missing `var webpack = require('webpack');` at the top of your configuration file.

It works for me this way

Comment: Thanks that was it! Now may post another question, I just ran this config and did not notice any minimized file... missing a few more steps I see